# Вывод значений содержащихся в белом списке

Tags: python, python-3.x

На первой строке вводится количество пунктов «белого списка». 
Затем — сами пункты «белого списка». 
На отдельной строке — количество запросов, которые нужно проанализировать. 
Затем — сами запросы.
После выводятся те запросы из введённых, которые есть в «белом списке».

**Код с ошибкой:**

```
list1=int(input())
white_list=[]
s2=[]

for white in range(list1):
    white_list.append(input())

search_num=int(input())
searches=[]

for search in range(search_num):
    searches.append(input())

print(white_list)    
print(searches)

if search_num>list1:
    for asd in range(search_num-list1):
        white_list.append('')

for i in range(search_num):
    if white_list(i) in searchs:
        s2.append(i)

for output in range(len(s2)):
    print(searches[s2[output]])
```

**Ошибка:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/python/8.py", line 22, in <module>
    if white_list(i) in searchs:
builtins.TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

**Ввод:**

```
3
h12
h21
h11
4
h8685665
h12
h745646
h21
```

**Желаемый вывод:**

```
h12
h21
```

**Ввод:**

```
1
asd
4
asd
567443423424167475687
7567548768564u4675477
asd
```

**Желаемый вывод:**

```
asd
asd
```

Comment: А зачем вы пробуете доступ к элементам списка через ()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обращение к элементу списка осуществляется через квадратные скобки, а не круглые.

Должно быть так:

```
white_list[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы отфильтровать строки во вводе согласно «белому списку»:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 
import sys
from itertools import islice 

input_file = map(str.strip, sys.stdin)
read_lines = lambda: islice(input_file, int(next(input_file)))
whitelist = set(read_lines())
for whitelisted_line in filter(whitelist.__contains__, read_lines()):
    print(whitelisted_line)
```

[Результат для первого примера в вопросе](https://ideone.com/djGCzS):

```
h12
h21
```

[Результат для второго примера](https://ideone.com/810iYF), также совпадает:

```
asd
asd
```